# Count no. of time echo is used

Tags: linux

How to count the number of times 'echo' command is used in a terminal?

I tried using echo echo but that doesn't work.
it is not even given in the mannual of echo.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're asking, but here is simple alias that counts every use of your `echo`.

```
$ echos=-1
$ alias echo='echos=$((echos+1)); echo'
$ echo lol
lol
$ echo rofl
rofl
$ echo $echos
2
```